# Как написать условие, чтобы при парсинге данных не выводилось время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть задача - вытащить с сайта название банков, цену покупки и продажи валют. В таблице на странице банка есть еще время(которое мне не нужно). Не понимаю как записать условие, при котором время не будет учитываться и достанется только нужные мне данные.

[Сам сайт](https://www.vbr.ru/banki/kurs-valut/prodaja-usd/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

    class Parse():
        def __init__(self, url):
            self.url = url
            self.values = []
            source = requests.get(self.url)
            self.html = BS(source.text, 'lxml')
    
        def get_content(self):
            table = self.html.find('table' , {'class' : 'common-table detail_table_highlight currency-new-table mobile-border-shadow'})
            tbody = table.find('tbody')
            
            for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
                td = tr.find_all('td',{'class' : ''} and 'class' != 'mobile-hide')
                for value in td:
                    if value.text != '':
                        self.values.append(value.text)
    
            return self.values
```

При таком коде, выдает такие вот данные:

```
['     Банк «Веста»', '24.12 15:36', 
'     Банк «Спутник»', '23.12 10:48', 
'     Всероссийский Банк Развития Регионов', '24.12 11:02', 
'     Муниципальный Камчатпрофитбанк', '25.12 02:46', 
'     Нокссбанк', '25.12 08:13', 
'     Банк «Соколовский»', '25.12 09:59', 
'     Банк «Москва-Сити»', '25.12 09:52', 
'     Банк «Химик»', '25.12 09:42', 
'     БайкалИнвестБанк', '25.12 11:36', 
'     Кубаньторгбанк', '25.12 09:36', 
'     Заубер Банк', '25.12 11:29', 
'     Плюс Банк', '25.12 10:22', 
'     Кошелев-Банк', '25.12 10:36', 
'     Банк «Урал ФД»', '24.12 09:38', 
'     Банк Казани', '25.12 10:45', 
'     Тимер Банк', '25.12 11:36', 
'     Банк «Агророс»', '25.12 11:15', 
'     Владбизнесбанк', '25.12 10:36', 
'     ПромТрансБанк', '25.12 11:04', 
'     Трансстройбанк', '25.12 10:44']
```

Если убрать из кода `class'!= 'mobile-hide`, то мы получим все данные, вместе со временем:

```
['76,10 +0,0024.12 15:36', '76,62 +0,0024.12 15:36', 
'75,00 +1,0023.12 10:48', '77,00 +0,0023.12 10:48', 
'74,20 +0,0024.12 11:40', '75,10 +0,0024.12 11:40', 
'73,88 +0,0024.12 11:02', '76,13 +0,0024.12 11:02', 
'73,85 +0,2525.12 02:46', '74,60 -0,8525.12 02:46', 
'73,80 -0,7025.12 08:13', '75,60 -0,6025.12 08:13', 
'73,75 -0,8025.12 09:59', '74,85 -0,7525.12 09:59', 
'73,70 -0,8025.12 09:52', '75,00 -1,0025.12 09:52', 
'73,70 -1,3025.12 09:42', '74,25 -1,1525.12 09:42', 
'73,67 +0,0725.12 11:36', '73,95 -0,0525.12 11:36', 
'73,65 -0,2524.12 19:53', '75,05 -0,2524.12 19:53', 
'73,62 -0,4025.12 09:36', '74,44 -0,1425.12 09:36', 
'73,61 +0,1025.12 11:29', '74,09 -0,1025.12 11:29', 
'73,60 -0,1025.12 10:22', '74,20 -0,3025.12 10:22', 
'73,60 -0,1025.12 10:36', '74,10 -0,2025.12 10:36', 
'73,56 -0,0524.12 09:38', '76,07 -0,0524.12 09:38', 
'73,55 -0,1125.12 10:45', '73,99 -0,2225.12 10:45', 
'73,54 +0,0125.12 11:36', '74,09 -0,1325.12 11:36', 
'73,51 -0,5025.12 11:15', '74,08 -0,0725.12 11:15', 
'73,50 -0,3025.12 10:36', '74,30 
-0,5025.12 10:36', 'Покупаете  USDПродаете  RUBСвернуть']
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `{'class' : ''} and 'class' != 'mobile-hide'` странное условие, не уверен, что такое работает как вы хотите. Лучше сделайте выборку без заданного `class` и в цикле обрабатывайте по `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал выборку и обработку

А так, в этой строке `td_name, _, td_buy, td_sell = tds` происходит игнорирование ячейки таблицы с временем.

[Посмотрите:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e0e74825d80b7b11830497c28db6d6309a62e3b5/html_parsing/www_vbr_ru__banki__kurs_valut__prodaja_usd.py#L18)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.vbr.ru/banki/kurs-valut/prodaja-usd/'

rs = requests.get(URL)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

items = []
for tr in root.select('#bank_table > .show-detail'):
    tds = tr.select('td')
    td_name, _, td_buy, td_sell = tds

    name = td_name.get_text(strip=True)
    buy = td_buy.select_one('.currency-price').get_text(strip=True)
    sell = td_sell.select_one('.currency-price').get_text(strip=True)

    items.append((name, buy, sell))

print(f'Items ({len(items)}):')
for i, (name, buy, sell) in enumerate(items, 1):
    print(f'  {i:2}. {name!r}, buy={buy}, sell={sell}')
```

Результат:

```
Items (20):
   1. 'Банк «Веста»', buy=76,10, sell=76,62
   2. 'Банк «Спутник»', buy=75,00, sell=77,00
   3. 'Всероссийский Банк Развития Регионов', buy=73,88, sell=76,13
   4. 'Муниципальный Камчатпрофитбанк', buy=73,85, sell=74,60
   5. 'Нокссбанк', buy=73,80, sell=75,60
   6. 'Банк «Соколовский»', buy=73,75, sell=74,85
   7. 'Плюс Банк', buy=73,70, sell=74,00
   8. 'Банк «Москва-Сити»', buy=73,70, sell=75,00
   9. 'Банк «Химик»', buy=73,70, sell=74,25
  10. 'БайкалИнвестБанк', buy=73,67, sell=73,95
  11. 'Кубаньторгбанк', buy=73,62, sell=74,44
  12. 'Заубер Банк', buy=73,61, sell=74,09
  13. 'Кошелев-Банк', buy=73,60, sell=74,10
  14. 'Банк Казани', buy=73,55, sell=73,99
  15. 'Тимер Банк', buy=73,54, sell=74,09
  16. 'Банк «Агророс»', buy=73,51, sell=74,08
  17. 'Владбизнесбанк', buy=73,50, sell=74,15
  18. 'Банк «Новый век»', buy=73,50, sell=74,04
  19. 'ПромТрансБанк', buy=73,50, sell=74,50
  20. 'Трансстройбанк', buy=73,50, sell=74,10
```